# How do I find PHP file that contains content of my page?

Tags: php, pages, content

Let's say I have created a page in admin dashboard and put some content in it.

How I can find PHP file in my hosting file manager that contains that content?

[image: screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 3):

You are under a fundamentally wrong assumption: The content you input via the administrative back-end *does not live in a file, but in the [database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)*, specifically in the `wp_posts` table.

Do not be misguided by the table's name, a "page" is technically a post of *type* page.

If you attempted to find the content you created via your "hosting file manager", it is very likely your hoster also provides you with a tool to explore your database - In 90+% of cases, that'll be "phpMyAdmin".

Answer (score 2):

That content is in the database, not in any template. The page that displays that database content could be page.php, or a custom template, depending on your theme and page.

Comment: Got it. I'm new to wordpress and hopefully you can help me to resolve this issue: I want to put an image behind DIV accordion, but I don't know how. My theme has content builder, but I doubt it can build layers. http://i.imgur.com/u3yukCp.jpg   ----   http://i.imgur.com/IO9eBw8.jpg   That's theme that I'm using - http://themeforest.net/item/bretheon-premium-wordpress-theme/4001061  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would update your question with this, rather than put it in a comment. However, I would suggest that this is too localized an issue for WPSE.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. The content of your Page is stored in the database, not in the PHP files.